# Can I use \let\foo\foo

Tags: tex-core

I am using TexStudio and define some personal commands with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{bar}`. Unfortunately my TexStudio does not recognize `\foo` as a new command. Thus I had the idea to write

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{bar} \let\foo\foo
```

Now TexStudio recognizes `\foo` as a command. I want to ask, if the construction `\let\foo\foo` has some drawbacks or is forbidden for some reason.

Comment: Well, this works and has no drawbacks, as far as I know, but the question should be rather: Why does `TeXStudio` not recognize macros being defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` ?

Comment: No problem as far as I can see; but wouldn't it be better to ask TeXStudio maintainers to add support for such standard constructions?

Comment: To be on the 'safe' side: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\foohelper}{bar} \let\foo\foohelper`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer better would be `\let\foo\relax\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{bar}`, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem whatsoever for `\DeclareRobustCommand` with my version of TeXStudio

[image]

The problem appears with `\NewDocumentCommand`, instead, but the solution is not using `\let\fooNDC\fooNDC`, but rather `\providecommand`. Indeed, if I add the `\let`, the orange background doesn't disappear.

[image]

Of course, asking for TeXStudio support would be the best solution. By the way, TeXStudio recognizes `\NewDocumentCommand` as soon as `\usepackage{xparse}` is scanned, but not commands defined with it. Probably it's an easy fix for the developers.

[image]